# SHELL-- Date format validation

Tags: shell

How can I check whether the format of date is correct without date command being printed?

```
date -d $datum +"%Y-%m-%d"

if [ $? -ne 0 ] ;then
echo error
exit
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ date -d "$datum" +"%Y-%m-%d" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "OK" || echo "ERROR"
```

If the `date` command returns exit code `0` then `OK` will be printed, otherwise `ERROR` will be printed.

Comment: It just outputs current date and successfully exits if `-d` argument is empty or doesn't include separator. Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/18731444/5113030.