# date validation for a custom format in shell

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

i am writing a  generic script for the custom format date validation .
here is the script

```
dateformat=$1
d=$2
date "+$dateformat" -d "$d" > /dev/null  2>&1
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    echo "Date $d NOT a valid YYYY-MM-DD date"
    exit 1
fi
```

issue is

- `sh  -x poc_col_val_date.sh "%Y-%m-%d"  "2019-11-09"`  expected is valid date, output also correct
- `sh  -x poc_col_val_date.sh "%d-%m-%Y"  "2019-11-09"`  expected is invalid date,  output is valid date

Comment: The `+` format string sets the *output* format. It doesn't affect input parsing.

Comment: ... the `busybox` implementation can do it I think, via its `-D` option ex. `busybox date -D "%d-%m-%Y"  -d "2019-11-09"` ==> `date: invalid date '2019-11-09'` and an exit status of `1`

Comment: is there any issue in the code . Busybox is getting me both inputs are invalid.dateformat=$1
d=$2

    busybox date -d '$2' -D  '$dateformat' > /dev/null  2>&1
    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
        echo "Date $d NOT a valid YYYY-MM-DD date"
        exit 1
    fi

Comment: @daturmgirl single quotes prevent variable expansion

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193070/100397

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/215659/100397

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I tested with below script you will come to know about valid and invalid date

```
#!/bin/bash
d="2021-03-20"
z="20-03-2021"
date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$d"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "its valid date"
fi
echo "========================="

date +%d-%m-%Y -d "$d"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "its valid date"
fi

echo "========================"

date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$z"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
echo "its not a valid date"
fi




output

2021-03-20
its valid date
=========================
20-03-2021
its valid date
========================
date: invalid date ‘20-03-2021’
its not a valid date
```

Comment: Why didn't you test `"$z"` with `+%d-%m-%Y`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use perl here. This uses Time::Piece which is a core module.

```bsh
valid_date() {
  # this function returns with the exit status of the perl command
  perl -MTime::Piece -se 'Time::Piece->strptime($date, $fmt)' -- -fmt="$1" -date="$2" 2>/dev/null
}
```

So

```bsh
valid_date '%Y-%m-%d' '2019-11-09' && echo Y || echo N     # => Y
valid_date '%d/%m/%y' '2019-11-09' && echo Y || echo N     # => N
```